# Retrieve text from textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have `<textarea></textarea>` on my html page and want to retrieve info from it based on what the user types into it. 
Say if the user types "Hello" in the textarea. "How are you" will appear.

Like so (code doesn't actually work, but just an example:

```
<script>    
    if ('msg'.value === "hello") {
        document.write("How are you");
    }
</script>
<textarea  id="msg"></textarea>
<input type="submit></input>
```

Hope that someone can help me out!

**Edit:** outputs the msg val, on submit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'msg'` is a string.  You need an element:

```
if (document.getElementById('msg').value === "hello") {
    document.write("How are you");
}
```

Comment: I think that this might work. How would I get it to output "How are you" with a <input type=submit...>. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just use the same idea of document.get... but setting it instead of comparing it.

Comment: Something like this? `if(document.getElementById('sub')) { // code you posted above }` (and I give my input the id of sub)

Comment: No, replace document.write with the declaration of the input.

Comment: `<script>function checkValue(){
      var inputval = document.getElementById("thisinput").value;
      //var inputval = this.value; // this would also work
      if (inputval == "hello") {
        document.write('How are you');
      }
    }</script><input type="text" name="thisinput" id="thisinput" value="" onchange="checkValue()"/>` This works but the input disappears after I enter the code. How can I keep the input shown?

Comment: You would need to use event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener specifically onkeydown if I understand what you're asking.